# Limit involving $\Gamma(x)$ and $\Gamma'(x)$

Tags: asymptotics, parametric, gamma-function

How can I evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \Gamma(t+1)-\frac{\Gamma'(t+1)L(t)}{\sqrt{1+\Gamma'(t+1)^2}}$$
Where
$$L(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{\Gamma'(x+1)^2+1}dx$$
?

The reason I want to know is this: I was playing around with the [involutes of curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Involute.html) and I decided to graph the involute of $y=\Gamma(x+1)$. The involute looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the $y$ value seems to converge and be asymptotic. And so the limit that I am trying to evaluate is the limit of the $y$ coordinate of the parametric equation as $t \to \infty$. Just thought I'd add a little bit of context.

Does anybody have any idea how to evaluate such a limit? Or even to show that it converges to a value? I have no idea how to even start with it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Numerically, the limit does not seem to be finite.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How did you figure that out? Can you post an explanation as an answer?

Comment: $\Gamma(t+1)-\int_{0}^{t}\Gamma(x+1)\,dx = t\,\Gamma(t)-\int_{0}^{t} x\,\Gamma(x)\,dx$ appears to diverge pretty fast, and the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\Gamma'(t+1)^2}}}$ converges pretty fast to $1$.

Comment: If it diverges so quickly, what's going on with that graph? Do I have the wrong parametric equation?

Comment: We can't exactly see what you put into the graph btw.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'll add that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Here's a link to the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/olv7cynwlm

Comment: The $L(x)$ looks much different over there.

Comment: Oh jesus, I screwed up the question. That's why. It's supposed to be the arc length, but I just put in the integral of $\Gamma(x+1)$! D:

Comment: I suppose you'll want to binomial expand the radical and use $\Gamma'(t+1)\sim\sqrt{1+[\Gamma'(t+1)]^2}$